# Cursor in input starts on left side of text on focus

Tags: javascript, search, input, cursor

https://mystifying-austin-2cfe16.netlify.com/

When a user clicks on the search icon, types data, clicks off the search and re-enters the input field, the cursor starts on the left of the text. any idea how to fix this? Thanks

1. Click search icon
2. enter something
3. click off the modal to exit search
4. click search icon
   Looks something like this "|wordsdsds" should be -> "wordsdsds|"

Answer (score 0):

Clear input value, focus, then revert to original value:

```
var value = $("input.searchinp").val();
$("input.searchinp").val(" ").focus().val(value);
```